# A past version of "for now" in reported speech

Tags: reported-speech

> She said to me, "Let's just stay focused on this issue **for now**."

**Question:** How would you convert this sentence into a reported speech sentence?

I don't know what I should convert **for now** into.

Comment: For the time being?

Comment: She said to me that we should just stay focused on this issue for now. The fact that her words applied then and not necessarily now is not a problem. Also, "for now" does not define a split second, but a vague period of as much as a month.